Lower bound for the rank of the sum of $n$ matrices
I found a mathematical note by George Marsaglia entitiled "Bounds for the rank of the sum of two matrices", where he proves the following result.
Let $A_1$ and $A_2$ be two complex matrices of the same size. Then
$$ \operatorname{rk}(A_1 + A_2) \geq \operatorname{rk}(A_1) + \operatorname{rk}(A_2) - \dim(\mathcal{R}_1 \cap \mathcal{R}_2) - \dim(\mathcal{C}_1 \cap \mathcal{C}_2),$$
where $\operatorname{rk}()$ denotes the rank, $\mathcal{R}_i$ (resp. $\mathcal{C}_i$) is the rowspace (resp. columnspace) of $A_i$, for $i = 1, 2$.
How does one extend this formula to a sum of, say, $n$ matrices $A_1, \dots, A_n$?
I conjecture that:
$$ \operatorname{rk}(A_1 + \dots + A_n) + \sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{rk}(A_i) \geq \operatorname{rk}(A_1, \dots, A_n) + \operatorname{rk}\begin{pmatrix} A_1 \\ \vdots \\ A_n \end{pmatrix}.$$
The first, resp. second, term on the RHS is the rank of the matrix having the $A_i$ stacked next to each other horizontally, resp. vertically.
I have run some numerical simulations by generating, each time, a large number (usually $1000$) of collections of $n$ (pseudo-)random matrices with integer entries and specified ranks, for some low values of $a$, $b$, $n$ and some choices of $n$ ranks. I could not yet find any counterexample this way. I am starting to think this could be true.
Note: I had written another conjecture initially, but the original conjecture was false. A counterexample can be obtained by taking $A_1 = (1, 0)$, $A_2 = (0, 1)$ and $A_3 = (-1, -1)$. In order not to clutter this post, I deleted the false conjecture and kept the one above, which may still possibly be true (or not).

Yes.
Let $A_i=U_i|A_i|$ denote the polar decomposition and
put $X=(U_1|A_1|^{1/2},\ldots,U_n|A_n|^{1/2})$ and $Y=(|A_1|^{1/2},\ldots,|A_n|^{1/2})^T$.
Thus $\sum A_i = XY$ and
\begin{align*}
\mathop{\mathrm{rk}} XY
 &= \mathop{\mathrm{rk}}Y-\dim(\ker X \cap\mathop{\mathrm{ran}}Y)\\
 &= \mathop{\mathrm{rk}}X+\mathop{\mathrm{rk}}Y
     - \dim((\ker X)^\perp+\ker X\cap\mathop{\mathrm{ran}}Y).
\end{align*}
Observe that $\mathop{\mathrm{rk}}X=\mathop{\mathrm{rk}} {(A_1,\ldots,A_n)}$,
$\mathop{\mathrm{rk}} Y=\mathop{\mathrm{rk}}{(A_1,\ldots,A_n)^T}$, and that
$$(\ker X)^\perp + \mathop{\mathrm{ran}}Y\subset\bigoplus_i (\ker|A_i|)^\perp = \bigoplus_i \mathop{\mathrm{ran}}|A_i|$$
has dimension $\le\sum_i\mathop{\mathrm{rk}} A_i$.

Your answer assumes that the matrices are square, but OP is interested also in the rectangular case, as can be seen from the counterexample at the end.

@Federico Poloni: I do not assume that matrices are square.

I realized that I used polar decomposition because of my operator theoretic background. It was equally OK to use the more simpler decomposition $A_i=A_iP_i$, where $P_i$ is the orthogonal projection onto the row space of $A_i$.

It took me a while to understand your second equality for $\operatorname{rk}(XY)$! You skipped a step, in the exposition, which was probably obvious to you, but anyway. Here it is. $\operatorname{rk}(X) = \dim((\operatorname{ker} X)^\perp)$. We also have that $(\operatorname{ker} X)^\perp$ and $\operatorname{ker} X \cap \operatorname{ran} Y$ have trivial intersection.

Can you please provide a little more details? For example, why is $\operatorname{rk}(X)$ equal to the rank of the horizontally concatenated $A_i$, and a similar question for $\operatorname{rk}(Y)$? If you could perhaps edit it for rectangular matrices, like you wrote in a comment, then that would be great. I am just worried that we are not multiplying the $A_i$ by the same matrix (either from the left or from the right). So wouldn't this possibly affect the rank?

(1) I really do not get it. What in my writing suggests that $A_i$'s are square? It works for any bounded operators between any Hilbert spaces. (2) It is by multiplying $n$-by-$n$ diagonal operator matrix, e.g., $(C_1,\ldots,C_n)^T=\mathrm{diag}(B_1,\ldots,B_n) \cdot (A_1,\ldots,A_n)^T$ for $C_i=B_iA_i$.

It is just that the only version I have seen of polar decomposition is for square matrices. I did not know about polar decomposition for rectangular matrices or, say, the version you have mentioned for bounded operators between any Hilbert spaces. One keeps learning in mathematics. I will think about the remaining part of your proof.

Sorry, but I still do not see why $\operatorname{rk}(X) = \operatorname{rk}((A_1, \dots, A_n))$, and similarly for $\operatorname{rk}(B)$. I guess I kind of see it if all the $|A_i|$ are non-singular. But in general, they do not need to be so. I know you provided a helpful comment, but even with this comment, I am not able to fill out all the details.

There are (square) matrices $B_i$ and $D_i$ such that $U|A_i|^{1/2}=A_iD_i$ and $|A_i|^{1/2}=B_iA_i$. ($B_i=|A_i|^{-1/2}P_iU_i^*$ where $P_i$ is the orthogonal projection onto the row space of $A_i$.) BTW, there is no need to use polar decomposition; $A_i=A_iP_i$ and $Y=(P_1,\ldots,P_n)^T$ works as well.

Ok, got it, if we use $X = (A_1, \dots, A_n)$ and $Y = (P_1, \dots, P_n)^T$, where $P_i$ is the orthogonal projection onto the rowspace of $A_i$, just as in your remark. I believe your proof is correct with this choice. Thank you so much!
